# Up to date HTML Labels on iOS

Tags: html, ios, uilabel

Not sure if stackoverfow is the right place to ask that, but I'm searching for an up-to-date library / category to add support of HTML in `UILabel`.

I've read about `RTLabel`, but the last commit was 2 years ago, and maybe there is something more supported ?
I need iOS 5+ support.

Thanks.

Comment: What content do you need to place inside the `UILabel` that requires HTML?

Comment: Right now, it is only a `<br/>`. I know I could use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` to replace with `\n`, however, having support of `<b></b>`, etc. would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MDHTMLLabel](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mdhtmllabel) - but only iOS6++ support,
these will be useful:
[Slash](https://github.com/chrisdevereux/Slash), [FTCoreText](https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTCoreText), [OCPDFGen](https://github.com/ocrickard/OCPDFGen)